# Adding variables to an array php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have the following problem:

I made a form in which the customer can add some items they want and when he's done he will press the submit button on the from, bringing him to the confirmation page. Where he should see all the products and next to them the amount of items ordered.

And there is my problem, i placed all the products in an array like so:

```
$producten = array("Pizza Margherita", "Pizza Funghi", "Pizza Hawai", "Pizza Quatto Stagioni", "Pizza Calzone", "Broodje Shoarma" ,"Broodje Donor", "Durum Doner", "Knoflook Saus", "Whiskey Saus", "Sambal Saus");
```

and i show it on the page like so:

```
echo "<table>";

    foreach ($producten as $producten){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $producten;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";

        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

As you can see the second `TD` is empty, here is where i need to add the amount of items ordered.

But i don't really know how i should make it so that i can add all the `$_POST` items which i currently have like these:

```
    $Margherita = $_POST['PizzaMargherita'];
    $Fungi = $_POST['PizzaFungi'];
    $Hawai = $_POST['PizzaHawai'];
    $QuattroStagioni = $_POST['PizzaQuattroStagioni'];
    $Calzone = $_POST['PizzaCalzone'];
    $Shoarma = $_POST['BroodjeShoarma'];
    $Doner = $_POST['BroodjeDoner'];
    $Durum = $_POST['DurumDoner'];
    $Knoflook = $_POST['KnoflookSaus'];
    $Whiskey = $_POST['WhiskeySaus'];
    $Sambal = $_POST['SambalSaus'];
```

i read something about making the input field name like `products[  ]` or something, but the problem is that i'm already using the names for a piece of javascript code on the previous page which, if i change all the names, disables the whole JS code.

I hope my question is clear for you guys.

But to rephrase it very short:

How do I add variables like `$Margherita = $_POST['PizzaMargherita'];` in an array and let them print out in the other column in my table.

Comment: `$someArray = array($Margherita, $Fungi, etc...)`

Comment: @RoyalBg i tried it like this but on the page when i run the code it shows Pizza Margherita Array,
Pizza Funghi Array, all below eachother.

Comment: You will need a second foreach, or a counter which is used for the keys

Comment: @RoyalBg Should i place this foreach inside the second TD or is this just completely wrong.

Comment: If, for example, `$someArray[0] = $Margherita`, then you can use `$i = 0; foreach ($producten as $producted){ // ... some HTML ... // echo "<td> $producted </td> <td>$someArray[$i]</td>"; $i++; }`, $i will increment on each iteration, so on first iteration you will get first `$producted` (don't name the array and the value the same way) and on the same iteration you will get `$someArray[0]`, on the second - you will get second $producted and `$someArray[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to associates posts values (lets say $_POST['PizzaMargherita'] for example) with the name of the pizza.

The easiest way is to have your initial array `producten` indexed with theses keys:

```
<?php
$producten = array(
  'PizzaMargherita'      => "Pizza Margherita",
  'PizzaFungi'           => "Pizza Funghi",
  'PizzaHawai'           => "Pizza Hawai",
  'PizzaQuattroStagioni' => "Pizza Quatto Stagioni",
  'PizzaCalzone'         => "Pizza Calzone", 
  'BroodjeShoarma'       => "Broodje Shoarma",
  'BroodjeDoner'         => "Broodje Donor", 
  'DurumDoner'           => "Durum Doner", 
  'KnoflookSaus'         => "Knoflook Saus", 
  'WhiskeySaus'          => "Whiskey Saus", 
  'SambalSaus'           => "Sambal Saus",
);
foreach ($producten as $key => $product){
  $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo $product;
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo $number;
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

This solution does not requires you to write all the lines like `$Margherita = $_POST['PizzaMargherita'];`

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put into helping me! this works just as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a specific element of an array can be done via the index. Im not sure if that was your question. I just hope so.

```
$_producten['PizzaMargherita'] = $_POST['PizzaMargherita'];
```

This will save you a lot of writing. It saves every POST element into the product array and names each index exactly as it is in $_POST

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $producten[$k] = $v;
}
```

Comment: It should not replace my item in the array, it needs to add a second column next to my array products in which it shows all the amounts, which are all my $_POST variables

Comment: @Farewyth it will not replace, because the keys are different

Answer (score 0):

I would make an associative array, using the key as the item and the value as the amount, like this:

```
$producten = array("Pizza Margherita"=>"2", "Pizza Funghi"=>"1", "Pizza Hawai"=>"2");
```

then you can foreach like this:

```
echo "<table>";

    foreach ($producten as $item=>$quantity){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $item;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
echo $quantity;
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(This is how I think you mean it)

```
$producten['PizzaMargherita']['Aantal'] = $Margherita;

echo "<table>";

    foreach ($product as $producten){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $product;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $product['Aantal'];
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

That should do it!

P.S. Krijg er honger van!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear but it is the correct and proper way to do this:

**orderpage.html**

```
<form action="summary.php" method="POST">
    Margherita
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="pizzas[Margherita]" value="0" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Fungi
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="pizzas[Fungi]" value="0" />
    <br />
    <br />
    Hawai
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="pizzas[Hawai]" value="0" />
</form>
```

**summary.php**

```
<?php
// uncomment the line below when you need to debug
// echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:15px;"><pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre></div>';

$total_pizzas = 0;

echo "<table>";

foreach ($_POST['pizzas'] as $producten=>$quantity)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "Pizza $producten";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $quantity;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    // make sure the user gave you a number before adding to total
    $total_pizzas+= (ctype_digit($quantity) ? $quantity : 0);
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "Total Pizzas";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $total_pizzas;
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";
?>
```

If you need help altering the Javascript please let me know.